# Cordov Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to create an android application in cordova. I'm facing below error.

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: D:\cordova\gatescan\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\bitpay\cordova\qrscanner\QRScanner.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\cordova\gatescan\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\bitpay\cordova\qrscanner\QRScanner.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\cordova\gatescan\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [D:\cordova\gatescan\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\10.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [10.jar:android/support/v4/media/MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem$1.class]))
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: It's likely caused by plugins in your project referencing different versions of the Android Support Library. Please post a list of the plugins in your project: `cordova plugin ls`

Comment: cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-qrscanner 2.5.0 "QRScanner"
cordova-plugin-swift-support 3.1.1 "SwiftSupport"


I add QRScanner plugin.